# $\perp \Rightarrow p$ Syntactic Proof

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus

Given the following axioms
$$\begin{aligned}&1. p\Rightarrow (q\Rightarrow p)\\&2. [p\Rightarrow (q\Rightarrow r )] \Rightarrow [(p\Rightarrow q)\Rightarrow (p\Rightarrow r)]\\&3. \neg\neg p \Rightarrow p
 \end{aligned}$$
and the deduction rule of modus ponens, I want to prove that $$\perp \Rightarrow p.$$
Can somebody give me a hint how to do that?

Comment: To be honest, I don't know whether it is actually possible to prove this statement, as I don't have any syntactic rule for $\perp$.

Comment: I think we cannot, unless (see answer above) we introduce $\bot$ as primitive and $\lnot$ as defined.

Comment: I just realized that axiom 3 includes the $\perp$ and therefore it should be possible. Your answer looks good. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Proof* :

1) $\bot \rightarrow ((p \rightarrow \bot) \rightarrow \bot)$ --- from Ax.1

2) $\bot \vdash (p \rightarrow \bot) \rightarrow \bot$ --- from 1) and *modus ponens*

3) $((p \rightarrow \bot) \rightarrow \bot) \rightarrow p$ --- from Ax.3, with the abbreviation : $\lnot p := p \rightarrow \bot$

4) $\bot \vdash p$ --- from 2) and 3), by *modus ponens*

> 5) $\vdash \bot \rightarrow p$ --- from 4) by *Deduction Theorem*.

---

*Note* : see Alonzo Church, [Introduction to Mathematical Logic](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0691029067) (1956), page 90.

Comment: Isn't deduction theorem a theorem in first order logic, and not propositional calculus?

Comment: @tomasz - NO; Ax.1 and Ax.2 are sufficient to prove $\vdash p \rightarrow p$. This, in turn, with Ax.1 and Ax.2 is enough to prove the *Deduction Theorem* : "if $\alpha \vdash \beta$, then $\vdash \alpha \rightarrow \beta$" for *propositional logic* (and the proof is valid also for *intuitionsitic* logic). See [Deduction Theoem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deduction_theorem) : in spite of the *incipit* ("In mathematical logic, the deduction theorem is a metatheorem of first-order logic") as you can see by the text, the proof use only propositional axioms.