# Proof of $\bot \Rightarrow p$

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus

I am asked to *prove* that $\bot \Rightarrow p$.

Of course, this is trivially true from the definition of a valuation, regardless of the value of $p$.

However it seems to me that this is 'jumping out of the system'. I interpreted 'proof' in this question as a formal proof, i.e. a finite sequence of propositions $t1,t2,...tn$, each of which is either a)an axiom, b)in the set of premises S, which here is the empty set, c) is such that if $\exists j,k <i$ s.t. $t_j=t_k \Rightarrow t_i$ then we have $t_i$. Essentially, modus ponens. Then each of the proportitions $t_i$ is true.

The axiom schemes are the sets of tautologies:

- $p \Rightarrow (q \Rightarrow p))$     $\\ \  \ \ \ \forall p,q \in L$
- $p \Rightarrow (q \Rightarrow r)) \Rightarrow ((p\Rightarrow q) \Rightarrow (q \Rightarrow r)$     $\\ \  \ \ \ \forall p,q,r \in L$
- $\neg \neg p \Rightarrow p$ $\ \  \ \ \forall p \in L$

However I have been messing around with the axioms and cannnot seem to get this to work. And in fact, I don't think it is possible to prove this 'within the system', precisely because the axioms are for general symbols, and if you were to replace $\bot$ by one of these, clearly $p\Rightarrow q$ is not generally true for any $p,q$. i.e. I think we have to explicitly use the information about the valuation. Is this an implicit axiom then?

EDIT: I see now that for the third axiom to hold for arbitrary $q\in L$, we need $\bot $ to be false (at least, provided that there is at least one otherwise false $p$)

Comment: Maybe you have to use the abbreviation $\lnot p =_{def} p \to \bot$. See [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/932237/perp-rightarrow-p-syntactic-proof).

Comment: Thank you @MauroALLEGRANZA . Your answer in the link is great. Would be happy to accept a link to it as the answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We have to assume the abbreviation $¬p =_{\text {def}} p → \bot$.

If so :

1) $\bot$ --- assumed

2) $\vdash \bot \to ((p \to \bot) \to \bot)$ --- Ax.1

3) $(p \to \bot) \to \bot$ --- from 1) and 2) by *MP*

4) $\lnot \lnot p$ --- from 3) by abbreviation

> 5) $p$ --- from 4) and Ax.3 by *MP*.

Answer (score 2):

You are correct that these are two fundamentally different types of argument in logic.  To attach some vocabulary to it, you have been engaging in **syntactical** reasoning up to this point, simply treating $\neg$ and $\Rightarrow$ as meaningless symbols that can be manipulated only as the axioms and rules of inference allow.  By contrast, **semantic** reasoning ties those symbols to the notions of negation and implication and we can investigate whether the propositions we've been developing syntactically can be used as a model for rhetorical reasoning.

So, you're faced with the challenge that you've been asked to prove that $\bot\Rightarrow p$.  You certainly won't be able to prove $q\Rightarrow p$ in your system (since SPOILER WARNING propositional logic is consistent), so $\bot$ isn't an arbitrary literal.  But if the symbol hasn't been defined in the system, then you are formally unable to reason with it until you are given either a definition or an axiom that describes how it can be used in the system.